# Time zone issue with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, mezzanine

I set the TIME_ZONE setting to UTC first. But now I want to remove it and be able to have different time zones for my users. When restarting the gunicorn and nginx it is still the same. The posts are 2 hours later than it should be.

This is what I got in the DB:

```
         publish_date          
-------------------------------
 2016-09-21 09:08:40+00
 2016-09-08 09:36:35+00
 2016-09-07 09:08:42+00
 2016-09-06 07:16:22+00
 2016-09-06 01:50:58+00
 2016-09-05 22:55:07+00
 2016-09-05 16:22:37+00
 2016-09-05 16:18:36.52146+00
 2016-09-05 12:22:09.292926+00
 2016-09-05 09:09:05+00
 2016-09-04 19:00:12+00
 2016-09-04 18:20:07.83214+00
 2016-09-04 11:01:58+00
 2016-09-04 10:02:29+00
 2016-09-04 08:37:43.421796+00
 2016-09-03 20:36:49+00
 2016-09-03 13:42:06+00
 2016-09-02 18:51:19+00
 2016-09-02 18:36:16+00
 2016-09-02 12:08:50+00
 2016-09-02 10:33:28+00
 2016-09-02 08:20:30+00
 2016-09-02 08:18:36+00
 2016-09-02 08:01:49.359479+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.18064+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.163647+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.145824+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.128807+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.109296+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.091886+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.076142+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.041784+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.025924+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01.009529+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:01+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:00.988107+00
 2016-09-01 18:54:00.971702+00
 2016-09-01 16:58:54+00
 2016-09-01 13:43:34+00
 2016-09-01 13:38:35+00
 2016-09-01 09:21:33+00
 2016-09-01 09:17:41+00
 2016-09-01 06:27:31+00
 2016-08-31 22:41:13+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.930632+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.914006+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.898492+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.880307+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.862554+00
 2016-08-31 19:23:59.846515+00
(50 rows)
```

It displays +00 which is UTC I think. It should however be GMT/UTC + 2:00.

When checking postgresql (show timezone;):

```
TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

What can I do about this and why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

UTC it's just fine. You should store timezones as `UTC` and then depending of your user's timezone/app settings timezone, convert it.

It could be a mess if you store different timezones in your database.

When you set  `USE_TZ = True`. Django stores date's timezone as UTC in the database. Then, depending on what timezone settings you have in Django, It will convert dates automatically from stored UTC dates.

If you set `USE_TZ = False`. Django will store dates as naive representation.